# SharePoint thumbnail retrieval options

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, thumbnail

I'm looking into options for retrieving thumbnails from SharePoint Online for an external .NET application using the SharePoint client object model (CSOM).

I've seen the following suggestion which apparently works for many files types (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, MP4), but I am experiencing many instances where it isn't working, even for images.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https%3A%2F%2Ftenant.sharepoint.com%2Fportals%2Fcommunity%2FpVid%2FBiking%2520to%2520Work.mp4
```

Could anyone explain why the above URL isn't working for various file types? Is it something to do with how the library has been setup? The content type?

Another option I've come across when browsing a SharePoint library and changing the view mode to Tiles is that the thumbnails come from another URL

```
https://centralus1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=...&inputFormat=...&cs=...&docid=...&access_token=...&width=...&height=...&srcWidth=...&srcHeight=...&cropMode=...
```

I've not found any documentation for this URL. Has anyone come across this URL before? Is it possible to access from an external application?

Comment: Any finding how to use ? https://centralus1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=...&inputFormat=...&cs=...&docid=...&access_token=...&width=...&height=...&srcWidth=...&srcHeight=...&cropMode=... ??

Comment: @MichaelCarter I've had no luck with that URL

Answer (score 0):

The **/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx** works in my test, check the screenshot below:
[image]

The Url like this:

```
https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/team/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/team/doc1/Document.docx
```

**More information**: https://blog.beecomedigital.com/2015/07/27/generate-thumbnail-of-a-document-stored-in-sharepoint-from-its-url/

Comment: That is the link I have been using but with inconsistent results. It doesn't always work for images and doesn't work for videos.

Comment: Managed to get the it working for all image file types. Still no look with getting video thumbnails resulting in a 501 error.

Comment: @SeanDooley did you found solution for video files?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo I never found a solution for the video files.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for files stored in SharePoint Online document libraries using the Graph API to retrieve the thumbnail URLs:

1. Open the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) site to check your REST call
   syntax.
2. Call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com:/sites/anothersitecollection:/drives`
   to get the document libraries as drives and save the ID of the
   document library you need. Substitute your SharePoint tenant for
   "contoso" and your site collection URL component for
   "anothersitecollection".
3. Call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!aXYZmss8ZEiVokyC-JytN274MKTABCdAqaqixLW2-0JqtL9COCftQr9Ct9neeDKJ/root/children`
   to get the documents in the document library.  Substitute your long
   drive ID for the example.
4. Call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!aXYZmss8ZEiVokyC-JytN274MKTABCdAqaqixLW2-0JqtL9COCftQr9Ct9neeDKJ/items/01EQBDECC66F3P3O5YI5ABCIGG7O6M4Q23/thumbnails`
   to get the thumbnail URLs.  Substitute your long document ID for the
   example.

From my blog post: http://blog.larslynch.com/2019/01/3d-and-other-thumbnails-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Thanks for the information @Lars. I will try and give that a go next week.